# Why the current on this vector diagram have coordinates like this?

Tags: circuit-analysis

It is an example from a textbook. It is a really basic example and the purpose of the example is to show how vector diagram works.

Here is the example:

[image: https://imgur.com/AjKmeH0]

and this is the vector diagram:

[image]

What I don't understand here is why \$I\$ has these coordinates. Shouldn't \$I\$ have coordinates \$ 1.5 + 1.5j \$ because \$ 1.5 \sqrt{2} \angle 45 = 1.5 + 1.5j\$ ?

On this picture it looks like I have coordinates \$ 5 + 5j \$ .

Can someone please help?

Source of pictures: faculty of electrical engineering and computing Zagreb

Comment: Please add a credit for the images (since it seems that they were created by someone else).

Comment: Yes I did thank you for remanding me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your understanding is correct.

The only thing I can think of is that the coordinates are for voltage and the current is superimposed on the *Re* (real) and *Im* (imaginary) voltage axes but is using a different (red) scale which is not shown.